# How to show show or hide text boxes in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How can I show or hide text boxes when i export to CSV or EXCEL in SSRS ?

I have parameter called Reports_Export which tells to show or hide those text boxes when i export to csv or excel.

`If Reports_export = 1` show otherwise hide when export.

Answer (score 3):

**Hide a TextBox based on an expression**

1. Right click on the `TextBox` => `Text Box Properties`
2. In `Visibility`, select `Show or hide based on an expression`
3. Enter your formula

If you want to hide the Text Box based on the output format, you may consider using the `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` variable.

Example:

```
=Iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV" Or Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)
```

Here is an article on this:

- [Hide/Show Items Dependant On Export Format (SSRS)](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/)

That way you won't rely on a parameter to hide the elements.